# Custom Logic on Paypal button

Tags: php, paypal

I want my paypal button to capture information from my custom form so all users need to do after pressing it is to make a payment. My custom form has only 2 fields: amount and email address. Is it even possible?
Anybody knows how to do that using php? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, then this example should be what your looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Paypal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <!-- Change the email -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@email.com">
        <!-- Change the return email after payment -->
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://google.com">
        <!-- Change the description of the item -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item name"/>
        <input type="text" name="user_email" placeholder="Please enter email" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="text" name="user_amount" placeholder="Please enter amount" value="">  
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
        <button type="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">Pay now</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove inputs with name="email" and name="amount" and mark visible inputs user_email and user_amount, fill it and send form